# How to display Craft Commerce subscription description from a linked entry

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I must be missing something obvious here but I don't see any reference to this in the docs.

Under Commerce Settings > Subscription plans > You can link a related entry to the Description but it is not clear how to display it on the front end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer by viewing the source code in CP. To display the content of the related entry:

```
{{ plan.information.<fieldHandleInTheRelatedEntry> }}
```